# C: My struct's properties don't change when referenced from an Array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm having trouble with an array in C that is supposed to hold several structs I defined earlier;

**The Struct:**

```
typedef struct
{
    bool alive; 
    struct Vector velocity;
    struct Vector acceleration;
    struct Coordinate position;
    float mass;
    int ID;
}Sprite;
```

**The Array:**

```
Sprite Sprites[10];
```

To make creating structs easier, I have a function that creates them for me:

**Create Struct Function:**

```
Sprite createNewSpriteWithID(int ID, int Mass)
{
    Sprite newSprite;
    newSprite.ID = ID;
    newSprite.mass = Mass;
    newSprite.velocity = VectorWithZero();
    newSprite.acceleration = VectorWithZero();
    newSprite.alive = 1;
    int index = returnAvailableSpriteIndex();
    if (index < 11 && index > -1){
        Sprites[index] = newSprite;
        printf("Sprite inserted at Index: %d\n",index);
        spriteCount += 1;
    } else {
        printf("Notice: Sprite not added");
    }
    return Sprites[index];  // FIXED MY BAD
}
```

This function makes me a new Struct, and then I assign values to some of the properties. However, I do not do this to position, because I want to change this myself.

**The Problem:** 
The issue is that when I attempt to change the positions myself, they are not reflected in the array.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // Create a test Sprites.
    Sprite Sprite_A;

    // Set Sprite Positions and parameters
    Sprite_A = createNewSpriteWithID(1,300);
    setPositionForSprite(&Sprite_A,100,100);
    printf("\nPOS: %f, %f\n",Sprite_A.position.x,Sprite_A.position.y);
    return 0;
}
```

I call a function called *setPositionForSprite*, which assigns a position to the position property of the passed sprite pointer.

**Set Position:**

```
void setPositionForSprite(Sprite *S, float x, float y)
{
    S->position.x = x;
    S->position.y = y;
}
```

This is where the problem becomes apparent. When I sprite the position shortly after assigning it in Main, it comes out as intended

*100,100*

However, when I print the Sprites[index_of_Sprite_A], it gives me garbage values. Why is this happening?

I can fix it by changing the change-position line inside main to:

```
setPositionForSprite(&Sprites[0],100,100);
```

But It is unfeasible as I have to recall what the index was.

**Why doesn't changing the properties of my struct variable change them in the array?**

Comment: `if (index < 11..` should be `if (index < 10..`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh returnAvailableSpriteIndex() returns an 11 if no position is available. Since zero is a valid position, I chose it to return a number > than 10.

Comment: I think I really fixed your code this time......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `createNewSpriteWithID()` function, you're returning `1`.

Again, `Sprite newSprite;` is local to `createNewSpriteWithID()`. You cannot return the address of `newSprite`, either.

Instead, you need to have a pointer to `Sprite`, allocate memory dynamically and return that pointer. Along with that, you need to change the return type of `createNewSpriteWithID()` to `Sprite *` and collect the same in another `Sprite *`.

Also, with a definition like `Sprite Sprites[10];`

```
if (index < 11 && index > -1){
        Sprites[index]....
```

is wrong. Array index in c starts from `0`. You need to change to

```
if (index < 10 && index > -1){
```

---

**EDIT**

well, your changes are not reflected in the *original array* because, from your `createNewSpriteWithID()` function, you're returning the *array element value* which is then collected in a local variable inside your `main()`. When you call `setPositionForSprite()`, you're passing the address of the local variable in the `main()`, so the change is being reflected in the local variable in the `main()`, not in the array element.

To rectify, use a pointer [i.e., return the address of the element in the array], as I suggested above.

Comment: There should not have been a "return 1", I fixed that in an edit a moment ago. My bad.

Comment: @Owatch My latest edit should give you the idea. Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: Won't I be returning the address of the local variable 'newSprite' then? Will this be reflected when I access the array? I set Array[index] = newSprite. Does this copy newSprite into the memory at Array[Index]? Or will Array[Index] point to newSprite so I can modify it later?

Comment: @Owatch we,, in that case, your `Sprites` array is global, right? you can use something like `return &Sprites[index];` and collect the same in a `Sprite * Sprite_A;` in `main()`. Will that be ok?

Answer (score 2):

`createNewSpriteWithID` returns the struct by value. Which means that a copy is made.

Perhaps you mean to return a pointer to the struct. You could alternatively have `createNewSpriteWithID` return the index that was chosen.

You also appear to access the array out of bounds. Valid indices are 0 to 9 inclusive.

Comment: Thanks. I had not previously known that I was passing the value, and it is now fixed to pass the pointer to the address in the array where it has been copied to. I have also fixed the array index problem you and several others pointed out. Thanks for your help! I already picked an answer but I have since upvoted yours as a good answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for that message, appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your function `createNewSpriteWithID`  returns an integer value, then you give its address as argument to function `setPositionForSprite`.
That is why you make access to the number, as to the object of your structure..

Answer (score 0):

You change the value in a temporary variable in `main`, not in the array.